# Ionic platform add - do I need to run this every time project is checked out?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a team working on an ionic 2 project. Do I need to run:

```
ionic platform add ios
ionic platform add android
```

on each team members computer or is this platform configuration saved somewhere and I just need to run a command to have all the defined platforms setup?

Answer (score 1):

In your updated setup, run :

```
ionic state save
```

This will add all your platform and plugin details to your `package.json`.
After the install in other systems, if platforms are not set,
do:

```
ionic state restore
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to run every time. one time is enough, it will create supporting files first time run.